# Richfaces 3.3.3 Collapse all panelBarItem on Page Load

Tags: jsf, richfaces

Does anyone know how to not expand any of the panelBarItem's when the page loads?  I can't upgrade to Richfaces 4.0 yet and need this fix for 3.3.3.  I've tried to use the panelBar's selectedPanel property and set it to an panelBarItem that I don't render but that just renders the first panelBarItem in the list.  Any ideas?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
      xmlns:genx="http://genx.findmespot.com/facelet-taglib"
      xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
      xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk"
      xmlns:sec="http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsf-comp/acegijsf">
    <ui:composition template="#{layoutBean.template}">
        <ui:define name="content">
            <rich:panelBar height="400" width="650">
                <rich:panelBarItem >
                    <f:facet name="label">
                       <h:outputFormat escape="false" value="#{bundle['featureConfig.tracking.header.text']}"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    panel1
                </rich:panelBarItem>
                <rich:panelBarItem>
                    <f:facet name="label">
                       <h:outputFormat escape="false" value="#{bundle['featureConfig.newMovementAlertSettings.header.text']}"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    panel2
                </rich:panelBarItem>
                <rich:panelBarItem>
                    <f:facet name="label">
                       <h:outputFormat escape="false" value="#{bundle['featureConfig.newMovementAlertContacts.header.text']}"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    panel2
                </rich:panelBarItem>
                <rich:panelBarItem>
                    <f:facet name="label">
                       <h:outputFormat escape="false" value="#{bundle['featureConfig.dockMode.header.text']}"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    panel3
                </rich:panelBarItem>
                    <rich:panelBarItem>
                    <f:facet name="label">
                       <h:outputFormat escape="false" value="#{bundle['featureConfig.altitude.header.text']}"/>
                    </f:facet>
                panel4
                </rich:panelBarItem>
            </rich:panelBar>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</html>
```